# WPF C# Passing xaml object as parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, parameter-passing

I have the MyUserControl class, which extends UserControl, with a parameter:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Control _owner;
        public Control Owner
        {
            set { _owner = value; }
            get { return _owner; }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass, for instance, a Grid within XAML as that parameter?

```
<Window x:Class="MyNameSpace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace">
    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
        <my:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl1" Parent="*grid1?*" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to implement the *Owner* property as a **DependencyProperty**.  This is the code you'd need for the user control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OwnerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Owner", typeof(Control), typeof(MyUserControl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnOwnerPropertyChanged)
);

private static void OnOwnerPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyUserControl)source).Owner = (Control)e.NewValue;
}

public Control Owner
{
    set { SetValue(OwnerProperty, value); }
    get { return (Control)GetValue(OwnerProperty); }
}
```

Then in the XAML you will be able to set the property as you would expect:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="A button" />
<my:MyUserControl Owner="{Binding ElementName=Button1}" x:Name="myUserControl1" />
```

(Please note that your example won't work, because *grid1* inherits from type *FrameworkElement*, not *Control*.  You'd need to change the *Owner* property to type *FrameworkElement* to be able to set it to *grid1*.)

For more info on dependency properties, see this excellent tutorial:  http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html

Answer (score 0):

U should use DependancyProperty for bindings as described ealier, and u can also use *RelativeSource*

```
Parent={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}
```